# How do I make alarmmanager execute after my application has been closed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to make my alarmmanager to rings although after my application closed.

But now my code don`t call broadcastreceiver after my application closed.

I reg my broadcastreceiver in my manifest.

This is code that setting alarmmanager

```
final AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent=new Intent(setTimeActivity.this,autoCheckReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("com.dayo.selfcheck.autoCheckReceiver");
final PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(setTimeActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And this code is my broadcastreceiver.

```
public class autoCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String TAG="autoCR";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent it) {
        Log.d(TAG,"asdf");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.dayo.selfcheck", "com.dayo.selfcheck.MainActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

this is my manifest file.

```xml
<receiver
            android:name=".autoCheckReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.dayo.selfcheck.autoCheckReceiver"></action>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

thanks!

Comment: You might want to use more inline code blocks, and use, e.g., Grammarly to have better capitalization and grammar. The post is somewhat hard-to-read as it is. The question title should also be a question or just a command: `How do I make alarmmanager execute after my application has been closed?`

Comment: Are you sure the `BroadcastReceiver` is not called? How do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You MUST specify `android:exported="true"` on your `<receiver>` declaration in order for `AlarmManager` to launch your `BroadcastReceiver`.

You don't need to call `cancel()` on the `AlarmManager` to cancel the `Intent` before you schedule it, as `AlarmManager` automatically does this.

You do not need to set the `ACTION` in the `Intent` for the broadcast, since you are using an explicit `Intent` (you have specified the exact component to be used).

You also do not need to provide the `<intent-filter>` in your `<receiver>` declaration because you are using an explicit broadcast.